# C# Open text file like Double Click

Tags: c#, winforms

in .net framework
when I need to open text file like double click behaviour I used following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

when I try to use in core I get this error

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string)
AccountManager.Setting.HandelString.Encrypt(string) in HandelString.cs
AccountManager.Main.Main_Load(object, System.EventArgs) in Main.cs
System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(System.EventArgs)
System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
...
[Call Stack Truncated]

[Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUlsm.png)

I read many questions and tried the solution and not work with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file with its default application (set in windows) by doing this:

```
Process fileopener = new Process();
fileopener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
fileopener.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + pathToFile + "\"";
fileopener.Start();
```